# How to check if xml files dumped from database are up to date?

Tags: c#, mysql, xml

I have a mysql database and the application which connects to it, dumps required tables into xml, imports some info from them and then works on this info.

However I have no idea how to check if these xml files need updating while application starts.

I thought about checking if number of entries has changed but if someone modifies existing entry it won't be updated. Overwriting all files each time and importing them again takes too much time.
Unfortunately I cannot modify database to create a field which stores a "last modification" information.

Have you got any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a modify/insert trigger. I you can do it.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html

The purpose of this trigger is to update another table when your table is altered.

Answer (score 0):

How can you not modify the database?  If that particular table is off limits to you, then make a new table (in that database or another), which holds updated information referencing the table you're trying to possibly re-query.

I often have these defacto columns in a table:

- `InsertedDate`
- `InsertedBy`
- `UpdatedDate`
- `UpdatedBy`
- `Active`

You can use a compbination of `InsertedDate` and `UpdatedDate` to check whether you need to pull the XML out or not.

Another (albeit ugly) option is to keep a separate "tracking" table that contains a copy of the XML values, and you can then compare the two if they are the same or different.  If different, get latest and use it and then update your tracking table with it.

Comment: Like I said I cannot modify a database because some stupid guy who was working before me developed our CRM software that way, that it crashes each time the database structure is altered... but thanks for your reply.